# How to browse list content when debugging dart app in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, webstorm

I often need to check content of list during debugging dart app in Webstorm (Intellij). When I do `evaluate expression` it shows me:
[image: screenshot from ide]

To see what is inside the list I have to manually evaluate each of: `some_list[0]`, `some_list[1]`... etc. Are there some more convenient ways of browsing lists during debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine when debugging Dart server/console application but isn't yet supported for Dart browser applications.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13889

I usually use watches like `_players[0]` to investigate the values. I know know a very convenient workaround ...